# Find duplicate in list using built-in functions only

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am a TOTAL Noob so please be gentle!

I have written this code:

```
def sorted_has_duplicate(numbers):
     numbers.sort()
     duplicate = False

     for num in range(len(numbers)-1):
         if numbers[num] == numbers[num + 1]:
             duplicate = True
             break
     return duplicate
```

The code runs fine and it does what it is supposed to do which is find the first duplicate value in a list if any and return `True or False`.

My question is how can I have the same function perform the same task if the list is not sorted (sorting is not allowed) and i can only use built in python functions?

Comment: For each item in the list, check if that item occurs elsewhere in the remainder of the list.  If so, it's a duplicate.

Comment: You could use `numbers.count(num)` as a good option

Comment: The duplicate I identified *also* ignores/removes 0 and None values; you don't need that functionality.  The remaining solution is equivalent to the one answer you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect nums in a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) as you iterate:

```
def has_duplicate(numbers):
     seen = set()
     for num in numbers:
         if num in seen:
             return True
         seen.add(num)
     return False
```

You can also shorten this down to:

```
def has_duplicate(numbers):
     return len(numbers) != len(set(numbers))
```

This simply checks whether the `list` has as many elements as its `set` which by definition has no duplicates.

Note that both these set-based solutions run in linear time because of a set's `O(1)` contains-check. The naive brute force approach of searching for each element in the list remainder

```
def has_duplicate(numbers):
     for i, num in enumerate(numbers):
         if num in numbers[i+1:]:
             return True
     return False
```

is quadratic because of a list's `O(N)` contains-check.